# Hide tax from Woocommerce Cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

how can I hide taxes from Woocommerce cart?

I want to hide taxes only in cart but no in checkout.

I'm also able to edit PHP code if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct hook to do that, You can copy woocommerce/templates folder to your theme and name it as woocommerce then find the file 'cart/cart-totals.php'...

Modify that file/remove code (as per your need).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `wc_tax_enabled` on the cart page to tell WooCommerce taxes are not enabled.

```
add_action( 'wp', function() {

    if ( class_exists( 'woocommerce') ) {
        if ( is_cart() ) {
            add_filter( 'wc_tax_enabled', '__return_false' );
        }
    }

});
```